# Which utility or UNIX command can help to submit a bulk of event data to Google Universal Analytics?

Tags: unix, google-analytics, universal-analytics

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference

In the link above the Measurements Protocol is elaborated. Suppose I have a CSV file with columns like EventName, ClientID etc and I'd like to submit it to the Universal Analytics system. Is there a UNIX command, utility or a third-party software that will allow me to submit that data from command line or any kind of a friendlier UI?

Comment: It's just http requests, so you can parse the csv in a shell script and send the requests via wget or curl or run a cli php script (which might use curl or fopen or...). You form the url as per the reference in your link (people seem to think there is some hidden magic but it's really as straightforward as it looks) and send it. Only thing is you should include a delay after calling a url since there is a limit how many request you can send in one go (20 hits that are replenished at a rate of 2 hit per second).

Comment: any shell script or smth would be great to start from, also some authentication aspects remain unclear

Comment: There is no authentication in GA data collection. Anyone can send data to your account once they know your account id.

Comment: So is there any slight chance you could just supply a very simple script and add it as an answer I would approve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a bash wizard myself so there will be any kind of ways to improve this ( I adapted an [example I found on the web](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bash-read-comma-separated-cvsfile/)), but here is barebone example.

To group the hits into sessions (if applicable) you need a client id. Client id is a mandatory parameter, but if you want to log each row from your file as a new session you can use a random number for the cid parameter.

However the example assumes that the first column in your csv file contains a parameter that can be used as cid. Be aware that a session has max 500 hits (so after that you need to switch the cid) and that there is a limit of 20 hits per session that is replenished at 2 hits per  second, so probably you want to build a delay into your script.

The example assumes a csv file with a semicolon as a delimiter (can be adjusted in the IFS variable). It also assumes that there are three columns, one for the cid, one for the page path, one for the document title. if you have more than three columns the last value (pagetitle) will consume all remaining columns (so if there are more than three columns append the columns names in the line that starts with "while").

Then the script simply builds an url (the variables from the line that starts with "while" are intefied by a dollar sign in front of the name) and uses wget to call the Google tracking server (the server returns a gif image which wget will store - I'm sure there is an option that tells wget to dismiss the content from the request).

```
#!/bin/bash
UAID="UA-XXXXX-XX" // Google Analytics Account ID
INPUT=data.cvs // Input file name
OLDIFS=$IFS // store default csv delimiter
IFS=; // set csv delimiter
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; } // nice error message if input file is missing
while cid page pagetitle // while there are rows in the csv read fields
do
    wget "www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=$UAID&cid=$cid&t=pageview&dp=$page&dt=$pagetitle" // call Google Tracking server 
done < $INPUT // no more rows
IFS=$OLDIFS // restore default csv delimiter
```

Obviously you'd have to make this script executable. I tested this (recent Debian/bash) so I'm rather sure this will work. It might be not very efficent though.

Comment: Also found this page that explains how to upload the files via GA UI: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6015078

Comment: Uploading only works to amend existing hit data - you cannot upload pageviews from scratch.

Comment: so I can't upload new events? is that right please?

Comment: You can upload campaign data, product attributes, custom dimensions or transaction refund data, but you cannot upload interactions like pageviews, events or transactions.

Comment: Is there any 3rd party software that does the job? So weird there's an API but noone can just upload the data from reports (say, Bing conversions).